# XML node with value

Tags: xml

I have validated the following basic example but is it correct? Is this really valid XML or is it simply bad practise? I know it works for XHTML but is this really a likely scenario?

Many thanks

A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <test>
   <mynode>
   value
   <inner>value2</inner>
  </mynode>
 </test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.valid XML only .But the below code is better

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <test> 
   <mynode> 
      <inner>value2</inner> 
  </mynode> 
 </test>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid xml, with [mixed content](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content).

Whether it's good practice depends on your needs.  I would personally generally try to avoid it.